# Pandas mathematical operation, conditional on column value

Tags: python, pandas

I need to make a mathematical operation which is conditional on the value in a second column.  Here is the setup.

Given a simple dataframe (`df`):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col1' : ['A', 'A', 'B', np.nan, 'D', 'C'],
    'col2' : [2, 1, 9, 8, 7, 4],
    'col3': [0, 1, 9, 4, 2, 3],
    })

In [11]: df
Out[11]: 
  col1  col2  col3
0    A     2     0
1    A     1     1
2    B     9     9
3  NaN     8     4
4    D     7     2
5    C     4     3
```

I can add a new columns (`math`) and then fill it with a mathematical expression based on the sum of 10 and `col3`.

```
df['math'] = 10 + df['col3']

In [14]: df
Out[14]: 
  col1  col2  col3  math
0    A     2     0    10
1    A     1     1    11
2    B     9     9    19
3  NaN     8     4    14
4    D     7     2    12
5    C     4     3    13
```

but what I can't figure out is how to make the expression conditional on the value in another column (e.g., only if `col1 == B`).  The desired output would be:

```
In [14]: df
Out[14]: 
  col1  col2  col3  math
0    A     2     0   NaN
1    A     1     1   NaN
2    B     9     9    19
3  NaN     8     4   NaN
4    D     7     2   NaN
5    C     4     3   NaN
```

For added clarification, I will be using a variable for the `col1` value in a `for loop`.  As a result, I couldn't get the `.group_by()` to work as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44724480/group-by-one-columns-and-find-sum-and-max-value-for-another-in-pandas/50358802#50358802) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42488141/python-pandas-groupby-conditional-on-column-values-in-group).  I think I'm looking for something like this...

```
df['math'] = 10 + df.loc[[df['col1'] == my_var], 'col3']
```

which I got from the comment in the second example above - but I can't get it to work.  It throws a `ValueError` for too many values - - that is, I'm trying to pass both the filter and the column of operation together but it's only expecting the filter.  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50932651/perform-a-conditional-operation-on-a-pandas-column) SO post also uses the `.loc` similar to my expression above - but with a static `col1`.

Comment: Your expression is almost right. You meant `df.loc[:,'math'] = 10 + df.loc[df['col1'] == "B", 'col3']`

Comment: @RafaelC, This is, in fact, what I was trying to do.  At least on the right hand side.  What's the difference between `df['math']` vs. `df.loc[:, 'math']`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using **`loc`**

```
df['math'] = df.loc[df.col1.eq('B'), 'col3'].add(10)

  col1  col2  col3  math
0    A     2     0   NaN
1    A     1     1   NaN
2    B     9     9  19.0
3  NaN     8     4   NaN
4    D     7     2   NaN
5    C     4     3   NaN
```

Comment: Or `df.loc[df.col1=="B", "math"] = df.col3+10`

Comment: Hmm, didn't know you could create columns like that, thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 5):

## `where`

I perform the math then mask it using `pandas.Series.where` by passing the boolean series `df.col1.eq('B')`

```
df.assign(math=df.col3.add(10).where(df.col1.eq('B')))

  col1  col2  col3  math
0    A     2     0   NaN
1    A     1     1   NaN
2    B     9     9  19.0
3  NaN     8     4   NaN
4    D     7     2   NaN
5    C     4     3   NaN
```

Answer (score 3):

Use:(Not a safe way to achieve it see the comment below )

```
df['New']=df.col3[df.col1=='B']+10
df
Out[11]: 
  col1  col2  col3   New
0    A     2     0   NaN
1    A     1     1   NaN
2    B     9     9  19.0
3  NaN     8     4   NaN
4    D     7     2   NaN
5    C     4     3   NaN
```

Update

```
pd.concat([df,(df.col3[df.col1=='B']+10).to_frame('New')],1)
Out[51]: 
  col1  col2  col3   New
0    A     2     0   NaN
1    A     1     1   NaN
2    B     9     9  19.0
3  NaN     8     4   NaN
4    D     7     2   NaN
5    C     4     3   NaN
```

Comment: This is not a good method of indexing. Use loc or iloc only. Don't mix indexers like this.

Comment: @coldspeed yep I know what you mean, how about right now : -)

Comment: The problem is the `df.col3[df.col1=='B']` which could've been done with `df.loc[df.col1=='B', 'col3']`. While it doesn't matter here, it may matter somewhere else (producing SettingWithCopyWarnings), and you've complicated this more than you needed to :)

Comment: @coldspeed yep , That is correct , when df is sub set of other dfs , we will receive the warning message for sure

Answer (score 0):

It was throwing `ValueError` since you were not using the loc correctly. Here is the solution using loc:

```
df.loc[:,'math'] = 10 + df.loc[df['col1'] == "B", 'col3']
```

**Output:**

```
 col1 col2 col3 math
0    A   2   0    NaN
1    A   1   1    NaN
2    B   9   9    19.0
3    NaN 8   4    NaN
4    D   7   2    NaN
5    C   4   3    NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also able to do the following...

```
df['math'] = 10 + df.loc[df['col1'] == 'B']['col3']
```

Which is a variation on @user3483203 answer above.  Ultimately, my `'B'` is a variable, so I modified for @RafaelC 's comments.