# How to perform conditional column operations in Pandas using list comprehensions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I need to perform column operations in a Pandas dataframe based on conditions. something like:

```
divide 'colB' by 1000 IF 'colA' is 'KG' ELSE 'colB'
```

I have already tried a normal FOR loop to check each element but it takes time. 
I need a solution similar to what is discussed here but with an ELSE statement as well. [Pandas mathmatical operation, conditional on column value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51034307/pandas-mathmatical-operation-conditional-on-column-value)

I need something like:

`df['TON'] = df.loc[df.colA.eq('KG'), 'colB'].divide(1000)`  ELSE...

It should fill with original value in colB if colA is not 'KG'.

Comment: link to the post I refer to above :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51034307/pandas-mathmatical-operation-conditional-on-column-value

Comment: `df['TON'] = df.colB.where(df.colA.ne('KG'), df.colB.div(1000))` ..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to what Chris suggested in the comments, you can also do [numpy.where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
import numpy as np

df['TON'] = np.where(df['ColA'] == 'KG', df['ColB']/1000, df['ColB'])
```

Comment: Thank you @chris-a and Ankur.  Both codes worked perfectly.  Is there a way to do multi IF statements in one go or do I need to do nested `.where` statements?

Comment: Depending on the complexity and situation, I would do multi np.where statements, or nested np.where statements if there are not so many conditions. :)